# Event Focus on EditText

Tags: java, android, events

I have a EditText where the EditText get a focus, it changes function of EditText, and when I loss a focus on the EditText it changes function again.

This is my source code:

```
tambah = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.total);
tambah.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener(){
@Override
public void onFocusChange(View arg0, boolean arg1) {
    try {
        if(..) //i want to check, i get focus
        {...}else //if i loss focus, the textbox do something
        {...} 

    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
```

}

For the result like when I click edittext for the first time, the edittext does not doing something. When I input "1000", and I loss the focus, the edittext changes to "1.000". But when I click again edittext, it becomes "1000" again. Please help me, and sorry if my grammer is bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

boolean flag = true;

```
 tambah = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.about_header);
            tambah.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

                public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                    flag = !flag;
                    if(v == tambah && flag) {
                        //format your text to 1000 here
                    }
                    else if(v == tambah && !flag) {
                        //format your text to 1.000 here
                    }
                }
            });
```

Edit:
If you need a simple formatter, you can use decimal formatter.

```
double d = 1.000;
DecimalFormat df1 = new DecimalFormat("#.###");
DecimalFormat df2 = new DecimalFormat("####");
String newD1 = df1.format(d); // 1.000
String newD2 = df2.format(d); // 1000
```

Comment: when i input edittext for twice, i still get a "1.000". i want if the edittext have a "1.000", and i click it again, it becomes "1000" again. how i get it?

Comment: Yea my auto generated variable names might be different, glad you figured it out :)

Comment: Ahh.. so it's not about focus. But when you click the editText second time, you would still focus the editText. If you want to do it like the way you told me now, you need to control it with a flag.

Comment: noo, i mean, when i click at the firsttime, the edittext does't have a length or we called it "null". so it doesnt anything, but when i input 1000, and i loss the edittext focus, it becomes "1.000". when i click edittext again, the number changes to be 1000 again. when i loss to another focus, it becomes 1.000 again. do get it? hahaha

Comment: Well that's what I said. You need to focus another view or manually clear focus of the EditText to change your focus. Pre edited version of mine works like that, when you change your focus, lets say you click to another EditText, your text would become 1.000 and when you click your EditText, your text would become 1000. Are you trying to change your text according to the keyboard show? Because the way you are telling me, it's not about focus.